# Ping a server on 192.168.20 from 192.168.30

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, ip, ethernet

So the way my network is configured, ethernet and wifi are on separate networks. I have a server on the 192.168.20 network (ethernet) and I want to be able to access the server from 192.168.30 (wifi). How would I go about doing this? The only way I can do this is if I plug in an ethernet cable to obtain a 192.168.20 ip, but I can't ping the server from a 192.168.30 ip.

Comment: Why put them into two subnets in the first place? You wifi can use the same subnet as your ethernet devices. If you want to keep a part of the subnet reserved for manual ip address assignments you can simply adjust the ip range of your dhcp server (your router). it's also your router's job to route between different subnets so you probably have some sort of misconfiguration in your local network.

Comment: I agree with the above. One subnet is vastly simpler and from here I see no reason for two subnets. Also you should be able to ping across - I do this from my host to my WMware NAT machines on a different subnet. Are your wireless machines set to public networking?  Is network discovery on or off?

Comment: 192.168.20 Nor 192.168.30 is a valid IP address.  What is the actual subnet?  You should [edit] your question to address the numerous questions you have received and clarify your question

Comment: @megamorf The reason they are in two subnets is because the ethernet subnet is for secure devices. The wifi subnet is for devices that aren't so secure. If a device on the wifi subnet is compromised, it shouldn't be able to access devices on the ethernet subnet. This is the reason they are on different subnets, but I was wondering if there was any way to allow the devices on the wifi subnet to ONLY access the server on the ethernet subnet. I wasn't sure if it was possible, so I asked here.

Comment: You should be able to configure a route between the subnets.

Comment: You can set up a guest router with a guest subnet, but then it does not need access to the secure network.

Comment: you should update this question with the make/model numbers of both routers, and how you have them wired.

Comment: Is this basically the same question as https://superuser.com/questions/1662636/?