# Two Internet links and two Wifi routers on two separate home networks - How can I make LAN1 access LAN2 hosts and vice versa?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, home-networking

I have this scenario:

LAN1 - Wireless Router1: IP 192.168.1.1 - netmask 255.255.255.0 - DHCP activated and Internet access.

LAN2 - Wireless Router2: IP 192.168.0.1 - netmask 255.255.255.0 - DHCP activated and Internet access.

I have some local devices like printers, DVR, etc on LAN1 and others on LAN2, and I would need to access the devices from LAN2 when I'm connected via wireless to LAN1 and vice versa.

I tried to connect both routers via LAN port, however it simply doesn't work. I tried to create static route on both routers and it didn't work at all...

The idea is to be able to access the local devices, regardless of which network/wireless router I'm connected.

Each Wireless router has it's own internet link, one has 300Mb and the secondary has 120Mb of bandwidth, I don't want to merge the links.

Does anyone have any clue?

Comment: Most home routers are not capable of this... This usually requires each router be interconnected on the LAN side and have an IP address on each line, and then route statements are added to route traffic between each network... Home routers are just not capable of this level of sophistication. If you had routers with DD-WRT/Tomato, pfsense, or similar devices, it might be possible, but I don't know of any stock residential routers that are capable of this level of setup.

Comment: If I could create the routes based upon the LAN interface, that would work I guess... but my domestic router AC1750 does not provide this kind of configuration. So I was guessing if there would be any other option.

Answer (score 1):

I think the main problem is that, when you interconnect *LAN ports* on the two routers (switches), you have two DHCP servers in one (merged) broadcast domain. If at least one of the routers allow you to disable its DHCP server and you can deal with configuring static IP on hosts that make use of its Internet link, then it shouldn't be a problem.

You can then either stick with two IP subnets and configure *additional* subnet route on every host (direct route, no gateway), or, make the router with DHCP disabled use a LAN IP from the *remaining* subnet (which should be used as the default gateway address on hosts that should make use of its Internet link, i.e. the "static" hosts).

If you prefer the latter the approach, make sure you adjust the DHCP range on the router that has DHCP server enabled, such that enough IP addresses in the subnet are available for the static hosts. (You can even make it use a larger IP subnet; better do that only when you really know how IP subnetting works and/or when you really need more addresses though.)

The above settings should be available on your router(s) unless they are e.g. some garbage from your ISP. Those are not exactly sophisticated setting options. (At least I can find them on my Linksys-but-really-Belkin router for laymen, and IIRC, my older Buffalo that does not even support DHCP reservation with MAC addresses.)